# Vue CLI: set default style language to scss

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

Is there an option in Vue CLI (like in Angular CLI) to set the default language used in component styles to "scss"?

Must I set `lang="scss"` in all my style markups by myself?

Comment: I'm 90% sure there's currently no option for this. But definitely seems useful. Might make a good feature request.

Comment: Not that I know of. If your code editor supports snippets or autcompletion, you can write your own component template, or just have it suggest the full `<style lang="scss">` as soon as you type `style`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to setup your loaders in webpack config in a correct order.

And in there isn't a specific item called scss it is sass here which will handle .scss

```
module: {
  loaders: [{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel',
    exclude: /node_modules/
  }, {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue'
  }, {
    test: /\.s[a|c]ss$/,
    loader: 'style!css!sass'
  }]
},
vue: {
  loaders: {
    scss: 'style!css!sass'
  }
}
```